# Extracting <tr> values from multiple html files

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I am new to web-scraping. I have 3000+ html/htm files and I need to extract "tr" values from them and transform in a dataframe to do further analysis.

Codes which I have used is:

```
html <- list.files(pattern="\\.(htm|html)$")

mydata <- lapply(html,read_html)%>%
html_nodes("tr")%>%
html_text()
```

Error in UseMethod("xml_find_all") :
no applicable method for 'xml_find_all' applied to an object of class "character"

**What I am doing wrong?**

To extract in a dataframe, i have this code

```
u <- as.data.frame(matrix(mydata,byrow = TRUE),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lapply` will output a list of documents. That cant be handled by `read_html`. Instead include all `rvest` actions in `lapply`:

```
html <- list.files(pattern="\\.(htm|html)$")

mydata <- lapply(html, function(file) {
  read_html(file) %>% html_nodes('tr') %>% html_text()
})
```

---

**Example**

Having two test files in my WD with content

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr><td>Martin</td></tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

and

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr><td>Carolin</td></tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

would output

```
> mydata
[[1]]
[1] "Martin"

[[2]]
[1] "Carolin"
```

In my case I could then format it using

```
data.frame(Content = unlist(mydata))
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply, it worked!! But I am not able to convert it into dataframe . ` dat<- as.data.frame(matrix(mydata,byrow = TRUE),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` is not working?

Comment: Then you should supply some sample data. I cannot tell what your data looks like. Anyways, try `unlist`...

Comment: THANKS A LOT! YOU ARE THE BOSS.

Comment: Final help: in the data frame all data points are filled in one column only(row wise) , how to filled it column wise, I mean one column for one individual html file. I hope I am able to explain you the problem.

Comment: I mean Martin comes in Column1 and Carolin comes in Column 2

Comment: Try `data.frame(matrix(unlist(mydata), ncol=length(mydata)))`

Comment: Thank you for all your help. Really appreciated.

Comment: As the list was uneven , so I tried this which works perfect `z1 <- max(sapply(mydata,length))`
`z2 <- sapply(mydata, function(x) c(x, rep(NA,z1-length(x))))`