# Extracting variables from multiple html files using lapply and html_nodes

Tags: r, web-scraping, lapply

I have downloaded several html files and saved them to a folder. Now I would like to read the files and extract some variables from each of them, then in return save each of the variables as a list.

However, I keep getting the error message: 
     Error in UseMethod("xml_find_all") : 
      no applicable method for 'xml_find_all' applied to an object of class 
    "xml_document"

I found this question on stackoverflow, which seemed to answer exactly my question: [Extracting <tr> values from multiple html files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45460261/extracting-tr-values-from-multiple-html-files)

However, the provided answer does not work for me. Could you help my find out what I am doing wrong?

My code is the following:

```
html <- list.files("C:/Users/[NAME]/Desktop/data", full.names = T)
```

yielding a list of file links that look like this: 
    "C:/Users/[NAME]/Desktop/data/99_html-code.html"

```
mydata <- lapply(html, function(file) {
  read_html(file) %>% 
    html_nodes('h1') %>% 
    html_text()
 })
```

Comment: Maybe a non-html file in the directory?  If you add `pattern = ".html"` to the list.files function, you'll limit your search to just the html files.

Comment: Hi Dave, thank you for your help! Unfortunately, that does not solve the problem :-/. The directory indeed contained 2 non html files, but even when adding the pattern and removing them from the folder I get the same error message. 
Also, the error message specifies that the method is not applicable to "xml document", I would think this indicates that it is a problem with the html files specifically.

Comment: Could I maybe solve this with a for loop instead? I have tried the following code, but it also returns an error (Error: Please supply css or path, not both). 

for (i in html) {
  mydata <- read_html(i, encoding = "latin-1") %>%
    html_nodes(i, 'h1') %>% 
    html_text(i) 
}

Comment: Without seeing which file(s) are causing the problem, I can't provide a good answer.  I suggest adding a `print(file)` before the read_html, in your lapply statement, to see which file is causing the issue.

Comment: Hi @ Dave2e, I found the issue, 2 of the files where empty, so that caused the issue. I have solved it with a for loop now to find the malfunctioning files

    for (i in 1:217) {
      mydata <- read_html(files[i], encoding = "latin-1")
      reads_name <- html_nodes(mydata, '._dTLine:nth-child(1) .col- 
   md-9')
  name <-  html_text(reads_name) 
  print(i)
  print(name)
}